# Natural Sort Abstract Class for Complex Objects

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

All,

I am creating a class to sort a list of objects by a designated string property in the class. 
I am doing this by inheriting from IComparer and the Sort() method that is provided by List.

My comparer class is abstract so it can be called on any object type, provided there is a string property to compare to, of course.

The problem I am running into is how to designate the string property type of the generic class that the class is working on. In the code below, I have a placeholder called "MyObjectsStringProperty" this is what I am struggling with. How to provide valid syntax in those places.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace NaturalSorterDemo
{
    public abstract class NaturalComparerObject<T> : Comparer<T>, IDisposable
    {
       private Dictionary<string, string[]> _table;

       protected NaturalComparerObject()
       {
            _table = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
       }
       public void Dispose()
       {
            _table.Clear();
            _table = null;
       }



       public override int Compare(T x, T y)
       {
           if (x.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower() == y.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower())
           {
               return 0;
           }
           string[] x1, y1;
           if (!_table.TryGetValue(x.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower(), out x1))
           {
               x1 = Regex.Split(x.MyObjectsStringProperty.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
               _table.Add(x.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower(), x1);
           }
           if (!_table.TryGetValue(y.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower(), out y1))
           {
               y1 = Regex.Split(y.MyObjectsStringProperty.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
               _table.Add(y.MyObjectsStringProperty.ToLower()
                   , y1);
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length && i < y1.Length; i++)
           {
               if (x1[i].ToLower() != y1[i].ToLower())
               {
                   return PartCompare(x1[i], y1[i]);
               }
           }
           if (y1.Length > x1.Length)
           {
               return 1;
           }
           else if (x1.Length > y1.Length)
           {
               return -1;
           }
           else
           {
               return 0;
           }
       }

       private static int PartCompare(string left, string right)
       {
           int x, y;
           left = left.ToLower();
           right = right.ToLower();

           if (!int.TryParse(left, out x))
           {
               return left.CompareTo(right);
           }

           if (!int.TryParse(right, out y))
           {
               return left.CompareTo(right);
           }

           return x.CompareTo(y);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't make this comparer generic.  Make it strictly a string comparer.  If someone wants to make a comparer for a type that composes a string, it's comparer can compose your string comparer.  This is the Single Responsibility Principle at work here.  This comparer should be responsible for performing a natural sort on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few things fundamentally wrong with the code example:

1. The class is `abstract` for no apparent reason. If you don't have `abstract` members in the class, then don't make the class itself `abstract`.
2. The class implements `IDisposable` for no apparent reason. That interface is primarily for dealing with unmanaged resources. It's not needed here, nor is it likely you even need to expose any mechanism to clear the private dictionary. The dictionary will be collected when the class itself is, and presumably until that happens the dictionary remains useful.
3. Using `ToLower()` as a way of implementing case-insensitive comparisons is not entirely safe; it is culture-dependent, but not in the way that works for string comparisons. At the very least, you should use `ToLowerInvariant()`. But even if that works reliably for you, it still results in creating a lot of new string instances for no good reason. The right way is to perform all string comparisons using one of the `StringComparison` values that specify case-insensitive comparisons, or the appropriate `StringComparer` instance (which would be appropriate for dictionary use). [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) are a couple of relevant resources for you to look at.

Second, it does not seem to me that you actually need a generic type here. As Servy mentions in the comments, it is better to limit the functionality here and compose it as necessary. You could provide a way for the caller to specify a selector, but given that .NET already provides easily-composed `IComparer<T>` functionality, that seems superfluous here.

So if you make your type look like this:

```
public abstract class NaturalComparerObject : Comparer<string>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string[]> _table;

    protected NaturalComparerObject()
    {
        _table = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // implementation omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
NaturalComparerObject stringComparer = new NaturalComparerObject();

myList.Sort((x, y) =>
    stringComparer.Compare(x.MyObjectsStringProperty, y.MyObjectsStringProperty));
```

Finally, I'll suggest that you probably don't really need the dictionary, which means your comparison implementation could just be a static method. The dictionary is there, it appears, to cache the result of removing spaces and splitting on digits, operations that are of course costly, especially in terms of object creation. But with a little effort, you could write a comparison that simply iterates through the string's characters, without having to create the intermediate objects that are motivating the use of the dictionary in the first place.

Since you're not caching comparison results, the only thing the dictionary helps you avoid is the overhead of the object creation. You still have the cost of comparing the sections of the original string, so an implementation that does the same thing but simply without creating the intermediate objects would perform about the same, but without all the extra memory overhead (even with the caching, that dictionary and the objects contained within are going to be costly for any scenario with a large number of strings to compare).